# How to see non-body returns?

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, postman

I'm using Postman to test Azure Function. For this code

```
context.res = {status: 200, body: "ok", txt: "hello"};
```

`txt` is nowhere to be seen. Anyway to check it or have to wrap it under `body`?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#response-object) the response doesn't contain the object you've specified:

> The `context.res` (response) object has the following properties:
>
> | Property | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | body | An object that contains the body of the response. |
> | headers | An object that contains the response headers. |
> | isRaw | Indicates that formatting is skipped for the response. |
> | status | The HTTP status code of the response. |
> | cookies | An array of HTTP cookie objects that are set in the response. An >HTTP cookie object has a `name`, `value`, and other cookie properties, such as >`maxAge` or `sameSite`. |

I assume the property `txt` is not serialized to the response so I don't think you could access it from postman or other any other client.

If you want to return some data you should add it to the `body`:

```
context.res = {
    status: 200, 
    body: {
        "message": "ok", 
        "txt": "hello"
    }
};
```